# Excel VBA non contiguous range more than 255 characters error

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have code which worked fine. But suddenly when I changed range of cells for copying to another sheet I'm getting the error message "Excel VBA Runtime error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed". I guess it's related to character limitation. So I tried to split the range to several zones and use "Union" function which then messed order of copied cells.
I would really appreciate any help or suggestion.

```
Option Explicit
```

Public Sub SaveExpenses()
Dim UniqueID(1 To 2)    As Variant, arr() As Variant
Dim Response            As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim txtPrompt           As String, FirstAddress As String
Dim RecordRow           As Long, i As Long
Dim DataRange           As Range, FoundCell As Range, Cell As Range, Zone1 As Range, Zone2 As Range, Zone3 As Range, Zone4 As Range
Dim wsDataStorage       As Worksheet, wsExpenses As Worksheet

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDataStorage = .Worksheets("Data Storage")
    Set wsExpenses = .Worksheets("Expenses")
End With

Set Zone1 = wsExpenses.Range("B3,D3,B8:F8,H8:J8,B9:F9,H9:J9,B10:F10,H10:J10,B11:F11,H11:J11,B12:F12,H12:J12,B13:F13,H13:J13")
Set Zone2 = wsExpenses.Range("B17,C17,E17,H17:J17,B18,C18,E18,H18:J18,B19,C19,E19,H19:J19")
Set Zone3 = wsExpenses.Range("B20,C20,E20,H20:J20,B21,C21,E21,H21:J21,B22,C22,E22,H22:J22")
Set Zone4 = wsExpenses.Range("B23,C23,E23,H23:J23,B24,C24,E24,H24:J24,B25,C25,E25,H25:J25,I14,C27,C34")
Set DataRange = Union(Zone1, Zone2, Zone3, Zone4)
```

'        Set DataRange = wsExpenses.Range("B3,D3," & _
"B8:F8,H8:J8,B9:F9,H9:J9,B10:F10,H10:J10,B11:F11,H11:J11,B12:F12,H12:J12,B13:F13,H13:J13," & _
"B17,C17,E17,H17:J17,B18,C18,E18,H18:J18,B19,C19,E19,H19:J19," & _
"B20,C20,E20,H20:J20,B21,C21,E21,H21:J21,B22,C22,E22,H22:J22," & _
"B23,C23,E23,H23:J23,B24,C24,E24,H24:J24,B25,C25,E25,H25:J25," & _
"I14,C27,C34")

```
    'check ID values entered
    For i = 1 To 2
        UniqueID(i) = DataRange.Areas(i)
        If Len(UniqueID(i)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Next
 
    'new record
    RecordRow = wsDataStorage.Cells(wsDataStorage.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    txtPrompt = "Saved"
 
    'check record exists
    Set FoundCell = wsDataStorage.Columns(2).Find(UniqueID(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address
        Do
            If UCase(FoundCell.Offset(, 1).Value) = UCase(UniqueID(2)) Then
                'inform user
                Response = MsgBox(UniqueID(1) & " " & UniqueID(2) & Chr(10) & _
                "Record Already Exists" & Chr(10) & _
                "Do You Want To OverWrite?", 36, "Record Exists")
                If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
                'overwrite record
                RecordRow = FoundCell.Row
                txtPrompt = "Updated"
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set FoundCell = wsDataStorage.Columns(2).FindNext(FoundCell)
            If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        Loop Until FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress
    End If
 
    'size array
    ReDim arr(1 To DataRange.Cells.Count)
    i = 0
    For Each Cell In DataRange.Cells
        i = i + 1
        'non-contiguous form cell values to array
        arr(i) = Cell.Value
    Next Cell
 
    'post arr to range
    wsDataStorage.Range("B" & RecordRow).Resize(, UBound(arr)).Value = arr
 
    'inform user
    MsgBox "Form no. " & UniqueID(1) & " " & UniqueID(2) & " Successfully " & txtPrompt, 64, "Record " & txtPrompt
 

End Sub
```

Comment: There's several options. Using `Union` is one - it might help to show how you used `Union`, and how it failed. Another option is simply to split `DataRange` into several smaller ranges, and loop each of those.

Comment: The UNION solved the problem with the 255 characters limit but it totally changed the order of DataRange. I need the DataRange in the same order as read.

Comment: Then perhaps try the second suggested option?